# Perseverance drove for the first time on Mars ! (on Sol 14) Can I find somewhere how much and in what direction?

Tags: rovers, curiosity, imaging, perseverance, mapping

[image: First drive]

Image Credit: NASA/JPL-Caltech. The image was acquired on March 6, 2021. (Sol 15)

Click on the image, and then again, for a closer view.

Is there an (interactive) map that shows the route the Perseverance rover has driven like [the one for the Curiosity rover](https://mars.nasa.gov/msl/mission/where-is-the-rover/) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, Perseverance has the same map: https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/mission/where-is-the-rover/

Comment: Magnificent, thank you !

Comment: Bookmarked! Thanks!